# Есть ли расширение в webstorm открывающее окно браузера в редакторе, чтобы писать код js и не альтабаться?

Tags: javascript

Я знаю могу разделить экран, я сейчас пользуюсь утилитой, которая закрепляет одно окно поверх других, но постоянно приходиться настраивать при новом запуске, и смотрится все это как шалаш из коробок + когда учу туториалы по видео, у меня много окон, и неудобно переключать внимание когда альтабаешься. В общем я просто использовал когда то live server, но он вроде не работает с Js кодом верно?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если я правильно понял, то после настройки окон редактора вам нужно перейти в Window>Store Current Layout as Default. Потом можно настваить хот кей для Window > Restore default layout

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]